# Document is not visible in community

Tags: community, lightning-experience

I have an img tag in  with URL such /sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/{...id}?operationContext=S1, but sometimes instead of image I see [image]

There is no any straightforward way to reproduce it can appear once in 100 loading of the page

How I can resolve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you use a [CDN](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_cdn_overview.htm&type=5)? Have you checked e.g. in Chrome's DevTools' Network tab, if other page elements show delays/failures too?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the image can't be loaded and is commonly caused by the community user not having access to the content document.

If it's an intermittent error and you're talking about loading the same page/image 100 times (your wording was unclear), then use your web browser's debug tools the next time it happens. Look at the network tab and see if there is an error when loading the resource. Also, look at the actual `src` attribute on the `img` tag to ensure the url path is as expected.

From there, you should have enough information to find the issue, or post an update here for others to further help.